# Putty error : Unable to open connection to hostname : Host does not exist

Tags: windows, putty, host

I am using Putty to ssh into some of the servers that I work on. I am able to connect all others except the one. Although I was able to connect to it before. Whenever I try connecting to it, it always give me error:

> Unable to open connection on myhost: Host does not exist

My firewall is off and I have even re-installed putty but that did not fix it. When I tried connecting to the same server using putty on some other windows system, I was able to do so.  I searched regarding this on Internet but did not find much relevant.

I am running putty on Windows 7.

What can be the possible issue?

Comment: Are you able to ping the host ? Are you still able to connect from the other PC ?

Comment: @Marged :  Yes, I am able to connect from other PC

Comment: Please post the results of traceroute from both computers (working and nonworking SSH connection)

Comment: @Marged :  how can I do that, i know he command in linux, it is traceroute    but what is to be used in windows ? sorry not a windows person. I tried with nmap but it is giving not able to resolve hosts

Comment: same problem, I can connect using the IP address works, but not using the host name.

Comment: Maybe a typo in the host name. I had the same error message when I had a comma instead of a dot in the IP address (which was very hard to see).

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was with the Url of the reposity. Check remote URL. It must start with git@github.com, not https://.

[image: See screenshot for example]

Answer (score 3):

As I understand you have three computers involved. At the same time one connection is working and the other one fails. So we can exclude that the ssh daemon on your linux box is hanging.
In lack of knowing their real names I will call your computers `linuxbox` (this is the computer you want to ssh into), `win7ok` (that is the computer that you are able to ssh from using putty) and `win7fail` (that obviously is the computer you can't connect from).

Please do a `tracert` from both Win7 computers:

```
tracert linuxbox.your.domain
tracert linuxbox
```

Add the results to your question as it will help us find out what is happening.

Perhaps it is also a good idea to determine the ip address of the linuxbox from win7ok:

```
ping linuxbox
```

or

```
nslookup linuxbox
```

Then try to connect from win7fail by using the ip address of the target computer, perhaps it is only a DNS problem (which might be as nmap is failing too).

To make all of this easier to understand for us please provide the real names of the computers as you use them in putty.

Comment: I understood before what you want me to do but actually I access the linuxbox at a particular port which all of these commands do not allow and that is why I opted for nmap

Comment: it is like : ssh -p portno. username@hostname

Comment: the above mentioned is the command to access that server 
and I am trying with nmap as : nmap -Pn -p portno. --traceroute username @hostname

Comment: The error message looks like your connection is failing way before the actual ssh protocol. So PLEASE just let us check if your network is set up correctly. Either you know what to do, then please do it on your own. Or ask others for help, that's fine. But then you should try to support them.

Comment: I think you took it in a wrong way . I told you what are the issues because of which I am not able to get the traceroute. By no means, i know the solution and that is why I posted the query here. Infact you are the only who has tried helping me at this. The above mentioned comments were just to give you the idea about what I have tried so far to get the traceroute.

Answer (score 3):

I used nslookup and then used the ip address it gave me to connect and it worked

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with GitExtensions. The solution was to remove the https url and replace it with git@gitlab....

WRONG:
[image]

GOOD:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this. I have a Cisco VPN I need to use to get through to the Linux machine I wanted to login to and check.

No Putty session would get through using the machines name.
An nslookup on the windows machine yielded the correct address.
I too connected right in via the ip address.
I tried to Google the error and it failed, so I suspected the wireless.

Disconnected and reconnected my WiFi and all was good.
I did it fast enough that open connections stayed open.
And new connections refering to DNS names worked fine.

Seems like maybe some cached DNS addresses were stale.

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS cache stores the locations (IP addresses) of web servers that contain web pages which you have recently viewed. If the location of the web server changes before the entry in your DNS cache updates, you can no longer access the site.

Following CLI command will do the trick:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```